What is the meaning of this phrase "plodded right on past"?
"Gagging on a dry throat, he chose some object as his finish line and, plodding up to it on weighted legs, plodded right on past. His head back and his heaving chest shot with pains, he strained on to a farther landmark."
Can it mean "he exactly ran past the object which he chose as his finish line" ?
Thanks in advance.

What makes you think "exactly" is involved? "right on past"? right past/right by in constructions involving walking, running, driving -- any form of motion or locomotion-- means "without changing one's stride or speed in any way".

I thought the word "right" here could mean "exactly" and as an adverb it comes between the phrasal verb "plod on". I know t doesn't make sense, but i couldn't understand it in any other way. However, I don't know the meaning of this phrase " right on past".

Compare: There was a child on the sidewalk with a bloody knee, but people walked right on past.  People did not stop or even slow down. They continued walking with the same stride.   Your runner did not stop or slow down at the object he had chosen "as his finish line".

@TimR thank you so much. I just saw your complete coment . Then it could mean " he kept running straightforward, though, he was tired. "

He kept running, yes.  His tiredness is expressed by "plodding", which means "making efforts to continue despite being quite tired, weary, or bored."

@TimR thanks again. How can I upvote your answer ? I don't see any like button or something like this.

"Plodded right on past" means it wasn't the actual finish line, but a landmark to aim for, and is now focused on the next landmark. Plodding isn't running, but a laborious walk.

It could be a staggering kind of run. Barely running.

@WeatherVane Thanks for the clarification.

He walked right past me = He walked straight past me. Same as He looked right at me = He looked directly at me. But it's obvious what the runner is doing. He's so exhausted that thinking about reaching the actual finish line would be too daunting, so he keeps selecting some point not too far ahead ansd pretending that is the finish. Except when he gets to it, he keeps right on going and selects a new "temporary / intermediate finish line" to aim for.

@FumbleFingers Thanks for explaining.

right past/right by in constructions involving walking, running, driving -- any form of motion or locomotion-- means "without changing one's stride or speed in any way, not stopping or even slowing down".

There was a child on the sidewalk with a bloody knee, but people walked right on past.
I was waiting for you on the corner but you walked right by me. Didn't you recognize me with my new haircut?
We were waiting on the train platform but the 8:17 went right by at full speed.

